# Scrapy Project Review/ Link Rules

Tags: scrapy

This is my second project and I was wondering if someone could review and give me best practices in applying scrapy framework. I also have a specific issue: not all courses are scraped from the site.

Goal: scrape all golf courses info from golf advisor website. Link: https://www.golfadvisor.com/course-directory/1-world/

Approach: I used CrawlSpider to include rules for links to explore.

Result: Only 19,821 courses out of 36,587 were scraped from the site.

Code:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from collections import defaultdict

# adding rules with crawlspider
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class GolfCourseSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'golfadvisor'
    allowed_domains = ['golfadvisor.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.golfadvisor.com/course-directory/1-world/']
    base_url = 'https://www.golfadvisor.com/course-directory/1-world/'
    # use rules to visit only pages with 'courses/' in the path and exclude pages with 'page=1, page=2, etc'
    # since those are duplicate links to the same course
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('courses/'), deny=('page=')), callback='parse_filter_course', follow=True),
    ]

    def parse_filter_course(self, response):
        
        # checking if it is an actual course page. excluded it for final ran, didnt fully
        # exists = response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-map').get()
        # if exists:

        # the page is split in multiple sections with different amount of details specified on each.
        # I decided to use nested for loop (for section in sections, for detail in section) to retrieve data.
        about_section = response.css('.CourseAbout-information-item')
        details_section = response.css('.CourseAbout-details-item')
        rental_section = response.css('.CourseAbout-rentalsServices-item')
        practice_section = response.css('.CourseAbout-practiceInstruction-item')
        policies_section = response.css('.CourseAbout-policies-item')

        sections = [
            about_section,
            details_section,
            rental_section,
            practice_section,
            policies_section
        ]
        # created a default list dict to add new details from for loops
        dict = defaultdict(list)
        # also have details added NOT from for loop sections, but hard coded using css and xpath selectors.
        dict = {
            'link': response.url,
            'Name': response.css('.CoursePage-pageLeadHeading::text').get().strip(),
            'Review Rating': response.css('.CoursePage-stars .RatingStarItem-stars-value::text').get('').strip(),
            'Number of Reviews': response.css('.CoursePage-stars .desktop::text').get('').strip().replace(' Reviews',''),
            '% Recommend this course': response.css('.RatingRecommendation-percentValue::text').get('').strip().replace('%',''),
            'Address': response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-addressFirst::text').get('').strip(),
            'Phone Number': response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-phoneNumber::text').get('').strip(),
            # website has a redirecting link, did not figure out how to get the main during scraping process
            'Website': urljoin('https://www.golfadvisor.com/', response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-courseWebsite .Link::attr(href)').get()),
            'Latitude': response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-map::attr(data-latitude)').get('').strip(),
            'Longitude': response.css('.CoursePageSidebar-map::attr(data-longitude)').get('').strip(),
            'Description': response.css('.CourseAbout-description p::text').get('').strip(),
            # here, I was suggested to use xpath to retrieve text. should it be used for the fields above and why?
            'Food & Beverage': response.xpath('//h3[.="Available Facilities"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').get('').strip(),
            'Available Facilities': response.xpath('//h3[.="Food & Beverage"]/following-sibling::text()[1]').get('').strip(),
            # another example of using xpath for microdata
            'Country': response.xpath("(//meta[@itemprop='addressCountry'])/@content").get('')
        }
        # nested for loop I mentioned above
        for section in sections:
            for item in section:
                dict[item.css('.CourseValue-label::text').get().strip()] = item.css('.CourseValue-value::text').get('').strip()
        
        yield dict
```

E.G. it discovered only two golf courses in Mexico:

1. Club Campestre de Tijuana
2. Real del Mar Golf Resort

I've ran the code specifically scraping the pages it didn't pick up: I was able to scrapy those pages individually. Therefore my link extraction rules are wrong.

This is the output file with ~20k courses: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1izg2gZ87qbmMtg4S_VKQmkzlKON3poIs/view?usp=sharing

Thank you,

Yours Data Enthusiast